# Unity Build Error `DirectoryNotFoundException`

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, compiler-errors

Guys why I can't build my project why this error? Is wondershare related to Unity? Why I am having this error when I want to build my application on my android device? Any help would appreciated
[image: Error].

Comment: That is an error saying that the player could not be built. According to your screenshot there are 5 errors total. 3 of them are on the screenshot and are related to a failed building of a player. You should probably check the other two.

Comment: the error is obvious to me: **there is no such directory**. find out why your code is trying to access that directory

Comment: @Bijan How can I stop this error

Comment: When I build other apps unity on android device it works perfectly but something is wrong in this project. Where can I find why unity is referencing to wondershare.

Comment: Uninstall wondershare, cleanup registry, restart PC, create a new project and copy project files. And see if it's still there

Comment: @Bijan I have uninstalled it restarted PC but what I have to do with registry??

Comment: @Bijan I did Everything you told me to do

Comment: @Bijan but nothing works I just want to know Where am I using wondershare in my unity project I searched in my solution but there was no results Why I am having this error?I appreciate your help

Comment: it looks like `System.IO.Path` uses `GetTempFileName` to generate a random file in that folder. look into **Windows Environment Variables** it seems wondershare changed it to its own path.

Comment: look for wondershare path in `TMP` or `TEMP`. or maybe `PATH`

Comment: delete the `Library` folder from your project

Comment: What happens if I delete The temp file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177961/discussion-between-bijan-and-youssof-hammoud).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the error message, it looks like Unity's build pipeline is trying to create a temporary file with a random name inside a folder which does not exist.

It is most probable that some information is being cached in `build.gradle` or other parts of the project.

- Close Unity
- Delete `Library` and `Temp` folders
- Open Unity

---

Afterwards, If you ran into an *access denied* error, restart your PC.

Comment: For those using Git, you can run `git clean -fdx` at the repo root to delete everything ignored in Git. Make sure Git is clean before running it.

Answer (score -2):

For some reason, I thought it a good idea to change your %TEMP% environment variable, which is used when building in Unity.

To change it, search for "System":
-"advanced system settings"
-Environment Variables
-System variables
-TMPDIR: change from wondershare to existing dir. 
default is: "%USERPROFILE%\Appdata\Local\Temp"

To verify the path is correct you can open run with "Win+R" and type "%TEMP%". This should open the new TMPDIR.

You might have to restart your PC after this.