# I cant build my game in unity. How can i fix it?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-games, facebook-unity-sdk

[image]
How can i fix it?

I tried restart and upload sdk. I need help.

I tried build app for google play store

they are errors :

Is this problem about my game or my settings or unity i dont know but i need fix it someone please help me!

```js
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 3 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002d8] in <e0956a95eb034b1e8f26f24b08543746>:0 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in <e0956a95eb034b1e8f26f24b08543746>:0 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

```css
BuildFailedException: Incremental Player build failed!
UnityEditor.Modules.BeeBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at <e0956a95eb034b1e8f26f24b08543746>:0)
UnityEditor.Modules.DefaultBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <e0956a95eb034b1e8f26f24b08543746>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <9c9519bc57e445a5ad440e3d3b321819>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.Int32 subtarget, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <e0956a95eb034b1e8f26f24b08543746>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)
```

```html
Internal build system error. BuildProgram exited with code -2147024893.
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.2.11f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Variations\il2cpp\Release\StaticLibs\armeabi-v7a\compile.rsp'.
   at System.IO.FileStream.ValidateFileHandle(SafeFileHandle fileHandle)
   at System.IO.FileStream.CreateFileOpenHandle(FileMode mode, FileShare share, FileOptions options)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
   at System.IO.StreamReader.ValidateArgsAndOpenPath(String path, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize)
   at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path, Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks)
   at System.IO.File.InternalReadAllText(String path, Encoding encoding)
   at System.IO.File.ReadAllText(String path)
   at NiceIO.NPath.SystemIOFileSystem.File_ReadAllText(NPath path)
   at NiceIO.NPath.WindowsFileSystem.File_ReadAllText(NPath path)
   at Bee.Core.Stevedore.VirtualFileSystem.File_ReadAllText(NPath path)
   at NiceIO.NPath.RelayingFileSystem.File_ReadAllText(NPath path)
   at Bee.Core.BuildProgramFileSystem.File_ReadAllText(NPath path)
   at NiceIO.NPath.ReadAllText()
   at AndroidPlayerBuildProgram.AndroidPlayerBuildProgram.SetupCompile(AndroidSharedLibraryConfiguration config, String name, AndroidTargetDeviceType deviceType, NPath sourceFilePath)
   at AndroidPlayerBuildProgram.AndroidPlayerBuildProgram.SetupLibUnityLibrary()+MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.InsertRange(Int32 index, IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at AndroidPlayerBuildProgram.AndroidPlayerBuildProgram.SetupPlayerBuild()
   at PlayerBuildProgramLibrary.PlayerBuildProgramBase.RunBuildProgram()
   at PlayerBuildProgramTypeWrapper.Run(String[] args)
   at Program.Main(String[] args)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

Comment: Give us more information, what platform are you building for, is this a blank project, were you able to build before?

Comment: It looks like some files are missing. Try reinstalling Unity to see if the error goes away. We can't help you if we don't have more information.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of error messages. Paste the text here so content is searchable.

Comment: I edited can you look now please ?

Comment: something similar happened to me because I installed unity/android build without admin priviledges on the computer (the unity hub beta went a bit nuts for a while)  have you tried uninstalling and re-installing unity and android build?

Comment: I am trying now

Comment: I had a similar issue when avast put in quarantine some files from the build folder.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with Unity, but, it seems to be complaining that it can't find this path:

```
'C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.2.11f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Variations\il2cpp\Release\StaticLibs\armeabi-v7a\compile.rsp'
```

Are you sure you have that in your computer?

Comment: yes i have that

Comment: I found this question on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51800235/unity-build-error-directorynotfoundexception

According to the error message, it looks like Unity's build pipeline is trying to create a temporary file with a random name inside a folder which does not exist.

It is most probable that some information is being cached in build.gradle or other parts of the project.

Close Unity

Delete Library and Temp folders

Open Unity

Comment: i tried but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue when I tried to build an apk, I'm not sure what caused it. But after a restart a managed to build the apk, also make sure you have enough space on your disk 3gb or more.